# Spring Data Elasticsearch use String as id

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

When I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch like this:

```
@Document(indexName = "app_rec_by_content_1", type = "user_rec")

public class UserRec {
    @Id
    public String id;
    public int userid;
    public int iid;
    public int modelid;
    public Date timestamp;
}
```

I got a exception:

> Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" MapperParsingException[failed to parse [id]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "1-245"];

Dose Spring Data Elasticsearch support String field as @id?

Comment: Should work. are you sure you are using @ID from spring data annotations?